# Python - Running Command Based on Result of If Statement

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python and coming from a JavaScript background where I am familiar with capturing the output of a command (success, error) and chaining that result to indicate my application's next command. Is there an approach to do something similar in Python?

For example, I am using the `gspread` package to interact with a Google Sheet. I am running the command `gc.open(*Name*)` that searches for a Google Sheet when provided a string `(*Name*)`, but if this does not return a value or if it returns an error as it currently does, `SpreadsheetNotFound:`, then I would create a sheet with `gc.create(*Name)` criteria. I was playing around with try/exception, but felt like I was approaching it incorrectly.

This is what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
if (API Call Finds the Sheet):

    Set regression_output = sheet

else:

    Set regression_output = creation of sheet with specified name
```

Current Code:

```
open_regression_output_sheet = gc.open(file_name)

for value in open_regression_output_sheet:
    try:
        regression_output = print("Test")
    except:
        regression_output = print("Error")
```

Error:

```
SpreadsheetNotFound:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a logic breakdown as such:

```
try:
    open_regression_output_sheet = gc.open(file_name)
except:
   print 'SpreadsheetNotFound raised, creating new spreadsheet'
   open_regression_output_sheet = gc.create('A new spreadsheet')
```

Comment: Be careful with this. This will catch all exceptions that could occur within that function call, i.e., not just the `SpreadsheetNotFound` error.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with try/except, but pay careful attention to where the traceback says the exception was raised. I'm guessing it was actually the 
`open_regression_output_sheet = gc.open(file_name)` line that raised the exception.

If that's the case, you need to wrap that line in a try/except like

```
try:
    open_regression_output_sheet = gc.open(file_name)
except SpreadsheetNotFound:
    # handle the exception or whatever
else:
    for value in open_regression_output_sheet:
        ...
```